# what's the criteria to prove this converges? $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^n+n}{n!+3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I getting a limit with some factorials that can't be taken away so there must be a trick...

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^n+n}{n!+3}$

Comment: Note that $5^n > n$ and $n! + 3 > n!$

Comment: Show that eventually the denominator beats the cube of the numerator. THis is sufficient by comparision with sum 1/n^2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{5^n+n}{n!+3}  \le 2 {5^n \over n!}$, so
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^n+n}{n!+3}  \le 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty {5^n \over n!} = 2 e^5$.

Alternatively, suppose $n \ge 10$, then
$\frac{5^n+n}{n!+3}  \le 2 {5^n \over n!}\le 2 {1 \over 2^{n-10}} {5^{10} \over 10!}$, and since ${1 \over 2^{n-10}}$ is summable, we have the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Use this $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{5^n}{n!} = e^5$$ and the fact that $\frac{n}{n!+3}<\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Note that $\frac{5^n+n}{n!+3}\le \frac{5^n}{n!}$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{5^n/n!}=0$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark